# Can't upgrade from 12.10 to 14.04 / Can't access the BIOS for clean install

Tags: 12.10, bios

Skype stopped working for seemingly no reason (I use 12.10), it would display "Skype can't connect" even though everything else was working perfectly. After checking a bunch of forums & questions on here, I uninstalled it and tried reinstalling. I get the error message

> > > "Package dependencies cannot be resolved / This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time"

I tried reinstalling it using the terminal but failed there too. Not too long after that I started getting System Error pop ups regularly (send report, new one pops a couple hours later), so I decided to upgrade, which I was putting off for a while. I'm by no means savvy at this so after figuring out I couldn't just upgrade straight to 14.04 from where I am I backed up my files and decided to do a clean install. I made a live usb using unetbootin. Problem is, I can't seem to access the BIOS at all. <kbd>F2</kbd> used to work when I had windows on this machine (Ubuntu is the only OS I have on it at the moment), but it just doesn't prompt anything now. Neither does <kbd>F12</kbd> or any of the F-s. It seems like it just speeds through the initial booting process?

Any ideas what to do at this point? I don't care about the data remaining on the computer, I just want to install 14.04 even if that means overwriting my disk.

I have a Samsung Notebook NP300V5A if that helps.

Comment: Hit the ESC key at boot. That should bring up the "One-Time Boot Menu".

Comment: I tried doing that, but it doesn't bring up any menu. The booting just goes through. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: Do you see the Samsung logo at all? Or does it boot directly to Ubuntu?

Comment: Boots directly to Ubuntu, I see a black screen from a few seconds then the purple screen

Comment: And you're shutting the machine down, right? Not restarting?

Comment: If it still isn't showing, take your batt out for 5 min, then put it back in and try again. You need to be hitting esc as soon as you see the Samsung logo.

Comment: I don't see the Samsung logo at all, and yes I am shutting the machine down. I'm gonna take the battery out and try again, hopefully it'll change something. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So I solved my problem though I still have no idea what the problem was or how the issue was solved technically. I disassembled my laptop, checked the components, checked the hard drive on another machine to make a new backup and put everything back together. I started the machine up again not expecting any change but the Samsung logo screen showed. I clicked <kbd>F2</kbd> and was able to access the BIOS, used a live-usb to install 14.04 and everything works now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to press <kbd>Esc</kbd> repeatedly at the very beginning of the boot, and you should see an indication of which key to use to access BIOS.

Comment: Sorry, I should've mentioned that I also tried pressing Esc & delete repeatedly with no results either. The only thing that happens is that the screen switches between the Ubuntu purple (with the dots) and a black screen with white writing, which I suppose is the booting process ? It doesn't actually register any change though.

Comment: If you're trying to press it at that point, you're doing it much too late.

Comment: Yes, @amanthethy is right : shut down the computer, then press the power on button and begin hitting `Esc` at the same time. Do it at the very beginning of the boot process. You can also try to hit `Pause` key once to pause the boot process.

Answer (score 0):

Try <kbd>F10</kbd> instead of <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Try holding down the <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> key before and during when you press the power on button.

1. Hold down <kbd>F2</kbd>
2. Press power button
3. Release <kbd>F2</kbd> after powering on

[Toshiba](http://forums.toshiba.com/t5/Satellite-Laptops-all-other/Enter-L655D-Bios-after-Fast-Boot/td-p/121341)

[Toshiba and Samsung are closely related.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toshiba_Samsung_Storage_Technology)

[Samsung](http://forum.notebookreview.com/samsung/709669-getting-series-3-notebook-np300-v5a-boot-second-hdd.html)

Comment: It sounds like they're not being shown the POST screen.